# How to align text box to right in uitableview custom cell

Tags: iphone

I want to put Label on left & uitextfield on right in my custom cell.

Textfield is displayed on left right now. Here is my code.

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:@"Name"] autorelease];
textField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
textField.placeholder = @"Name";
textField.bounds = cell.bounds;
textField.borderStyle=
[cell.contentView addSubview:textField];
```

how to achieve [label : textfield] pattern ?

Answer (score 2):

`cell.accessoryView = textField;`

Answer (score 0):

first of all initWithFrame is deprecated method. you should use initWithStyle instead. look throw available styles. maybe there you will find exactly what you need.